# get event after click google translate

Tags: jquery, google-translate

I use the google translator from here http://translate.google.com/translate_tools

However, the string that translated is too long, so I make it with this

```
display: inline-block;
text-align:center;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
width:19%;
```

So the string will be short and add "..."
And I add the full text on attr "title"

```
$("nav").find("li").each(function () {
    if (this.scrollWidth > this.clientWidth) {
        alert($(this).find("a").text());
        //$(this).find("a").title = $(this).find("a").innerText;
    }
});
```

So it should alert. I try to click on google translator and this not work.

This code is work because I add on the console.

How I get the event after clicking google translator. Is it possible?

Comment: Why did you comment out the title field?

Comment: it get the error because of $(this) but this function never be called after click google web translator